# "O app parou de funcionar", o que pode ser?

Tags: android

Boa noite pessoal, estou ingressando no mundo da programação mobile, e tenho um problema. A pedido de um exercício do meu curso, eu criei um projeto com um layout, uma Activity e uma classe. O projeto de acordo com o Android Studio está todo nos conformes, mas quando eu passo o projeto pro meu aparelho, ele instala e aparece a mensagem "o (nome do meu projeto) parou". Como não encontro erro nenhum nem na Activity, nem na classe e nem no layout, poderiam me ajudar quanto a isso? Eu não consigo usar o emulador porque a RAM do meu PC é um lixo, então só me resta executar o projeto pelo aparelho. O projeto tem a API 16, tenho 2 aparelhos com API 17 e 21, nos 2 o projeto não funciona.

Aqui está a Activity do projeto:

```
TextView txtTitulo;
EditText isbn;
EditText nomeLivro;
EditText tema;
EditText editora;
EditText autor;
EditText numeroPaginas;
EditText ano;
EditText edicao;
EditText preco;

Button btnLimpar;
Button btnSalvar;

Livros objlivros;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtTitulo.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
    isbn.findViewById(R.id.isbn);
    nomeLivro.findViewById(R.id.nomeLivro);
    tema.findViewById(R.id.tema);
    editora.findViewById(R.id.editora);
    autor.findViewById(R.id.autor);
    numeroPaginas.findViewById(R.id.numeroPaginas);
    ano.findViewById(R.id.ano);
    edicao.findViewById(R.id.edicao);
    preco.findViewById(R.id.preco);

    btnLimpar.findViewById(R.id.btnLimpar);
    btnSalvar.findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);

    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            isbn.setText("");
            nomeLivro.setText("");
            tema.setText("");
            editora.setText("");
            autor.setText("");
            numeroPaginas.setText("");
            ano.setText("");
            edicao.setText("");
            preco.setText("");

        }
    });

    btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            objlivros = new Livros();

            objlivros.setIsbn(isbn.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setNomeLivro(nomeLivro.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setTema(tema.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setEditora(editora.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setAutor(autor.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setNumeroPaginas(numeroPaginas.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setAno(ano.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setEdicao(edicao.getText().toString());
            objlivros.setPreco(preco.getText().toString());

            venderLivros();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ISBN: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nome do Livro: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tema: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Editora: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Autor: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Número de Páginas: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ano: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edição: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preço: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

public void venderLivros() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("ISBN: "+objlivros.getIsbn()+"\nNome do Livro: "+objlivros.getNomeLivro()+"\nTema: "+objlivros.getTema()+"\nEditora: "+objlivros.getEditora()+"\nAutor: "+objlivros.getAutor()+"\nNúmero de Páginas: "+objlivros.getNumeroPaginas()+"\nAno: "+objlivros.getAno()+"\nEdição: "+objlivros.getEdicao()+"\nPreço: "+objlivros.getPreco())
            .setNegativeButton("Livro Vendido", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
}
```

Log de erros a partir do momento que depuro o projeto:

```
07-22 20:01:27.828 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
07-22 20:01:27.828 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
07-22 20:01:27.843 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
07-22 20:01:27.843 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
07-22 20:01:27.851 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
07-22 20:01:27.882 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
07-22 20:01:28.101 13064-13064/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros/com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.dzcursoandroidvenderlivros.venderlivros.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Regra geral é uma exceção. Tem de olhar para o `Log` e ver o que apareceu.

Comment: Coloquei o Log na postagem

Comment: `NullPointerException` na linha 34 do `MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)`. É só seguir por ai, ver qual o acesso que faz na linha `34` e perceber porque ele está nulo

Comment: todos os logs de erro que apresentam uma opção pra clicar, aparece em cima as mensagens: Decompiled. class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8), e a mensagem em baixo: Sources for 'Android API 28 Platform (1) not found. E todos abrem classes diferentes, aparecendo a mesma mensagem no topo. Só esse da linha 34 q vai até a linha da classe Activity q foi interligado o componente EditText pelo método findViewById, e até onde deu pra ver, não tem nada nulo ali. Eu tento fazer esse download dessa API mas da erro.

Comment: Colega @David procure se informar sobre como fazer uma pergunta, pois não pode simplesmente jogar o código, precisa formatá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está nulo sim. Olha o seu EditText sendo declarado:

```
EditText txtTitulo;
```

Para variáveis de instância (isto é, para variáveis de objeto, em oposição a variáveis locais) isso é basicamente o mesmo que declarar isso:

```
EditText txtTitulo = null;
```

Aí você no começo do método `onCreate()` tenta chamar `txtTitulo.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo)` como se houvesse um objeto nessa variável `txtTitulo` com um método `findViewById()`, só que ela está nula, não tem objeto nenhum. Aí estoura a `NullPointerException`.

O correto é fazer (no `onCreate()` mesmo):

```
txtTitulo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
```

e repetir o mesmo padrão nas outras variáveis, não esquecendo de fazer os casts apropriados (isto é, onde for por exemplo `Button` faça o cast para `(Button)` e não para `(EditText)` como fiz no exemplo).

Naturalmente para a variável `Livros` isso não é necessário.

Comment: O problema era quase isso mesmo, tava quase tudo certo, mas ao invés de eu chamar a findViewById, era pra eu igualar, só precisei trocar o . pelo sinal de =. Vlw pela ajuda :)